# Buying A Computer "Case" Fan... Does It Always Run At 100% Unless Told Otherwise?

Tags: power-supply, power, fan, cooling, speedfan

***What happens if I do not plug it into the motherboard and it does not have a switch?***

I have seen fans before with an "off/low/high" switch that allows you to manually set their speed.

I have seen fans that plug into the motherboard and are controlled by the OS.

I am curious... what does a fan do by default when plugged into a PSU? Does it run at 100% unless otherwise told to go slower? This is what I would expect...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, kind of. Fan speed control is done by varying voltage or through Pulse Width Modulation (using a constant voltage and cutting it up into pulses to vary speed). If you're plugged into a motherboard, that's what it does. If it has 3 wires, the third wire tells the motherboard what's the speed the fan is running as. If you have a 4th wire, fan speed control is done via PWM rather than voltage control.

You can plug in a 2 wire fan to a 3 or 4 wire connector (though you lose speed feed back), and a 3 wire to a 4 wire connector (where you lose PWM control). You can also use a fan controller to control speeds.

Else, assuming the power source is unaware its a fan (as it would be connected through molex for example), and is at a fixed voltage, yes, it goes are full speed all the time.

Comment: Perfect, just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Like the other guys said, pretty much yes, but I can think of 3 exceptions:

1. A few fans have a built in thermistor that will adjust speed depending on temperature.
2. PSU's with specially marked Fan-Only PSU connectors (Antec TruePower 550W) can adjust the speed of the fan:

   [image]
3. If you plug it into the PSU molex using the 12/5 volt rails (7 volt) or 12/7 rails (5 volt) it'll be run slower, but at this point you're modding.

Answer (score 7):

That's pretty much it - if the fan just has a power connector for one of the plugs on the PSU it will run at full speed all the time unless you fit a controller unit.

[image]

Full speed ahead!

Answer (score 1):

There are some fans, especially the ones that advertise as "quiet" or "silent" that have interchangeable resistors which decrease the voltage from the PSU molex connector.  One of these fans I believe is Noctua.  Although expensive, they make high quality fans.